# Ajax/php/javascript Select Box not updating

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to update the select box sub_cat_id_1 with the database values after selecting cat_id_1.  The result I am getting is a blank box.  In troubleshooting, I've found that the javascript is receiving the correct id, and when running the ajax_subcat.php file by itself, it properly accesses the database and spits out the correct values.  Thus, I'm fairly certain that the problem appears to be somewhere in my ajax code somewhere, just not sure where.

I appreciate any assistance in advance for this.

**edit.php**

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function Cat_1_Change(category_id){
  var dataString = 'id='+ category_id;
  $.ajax
  ({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax_subcat.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(result)
    {
      $(".sub_cat_id_1").html(result);
    } 
  });

}
</script>
```

**edit.php (HTML)**

```html
<select name="cat_id_1" class="cat_id_1" onchange="Cat_1_Change(this.selectedIndex);">
<option selected="selected">--Select Category--</option>
<option value="1".>Example 1</option>
<option value="2".>Example 2</option>
</SELECT>
<select name="sub_cat_id_1" class="sub_cat_id_1">
<option>--Select Subcategory--</option>
</select>
```

**ajax_subcat.php**

```
<?php require_once("db.php"); ?>
<?php
if($_POST['id']){
    global $database;
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $sql="SELECT id, sub_cat_name 
          FROM subcategories
          WHERE category_id='$id'
         ";
    $result = $database->query($sql);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $response = '<option';
        $response .= 'value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['sub_cat_name'].'</option>';
    }
}
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: try removing `json_encode` in your php, just `echo $response`

Comment: no such luck.  I've tried nothing but echo "<option>Hello</option>"; in the .php file and it doesn't show up.

Comment: hmm...actually echo "<option>Hello</option>"; is now working...maybe it is the .php file

Comment: Issue resolved, see below.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a missing space in the php file:

**Faulty line**

```
$response = '<option';
```

**Replacement**

```
$response = '<option ';
```

Comment: to add up on this.  I'm pretty sure your only getting 1 option on your select box.